# Images do not display on a web page via a web server

Tags: html, macos, http, common-lisp, relative-path

I am trying to display an HTML page on the local host http://127.0.0.1:8080/ on  Mac OS X (10.9.5), but the images are not displayed.
I have a very rude program in Common Lisp acting as webserver, which simply listens and outputs the HTML page to the socket 8080.
The HTML page (after stripping everything else) is just:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>This is a test
    <img src="/Users/John/bs/images/MyImage.png"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I write http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in the URL of the browser (I have tried FF and Safari) the page is displayed but without the image. 
I have tried to change the img path from absolute to relative, in all imaginable ways (../../bs/images/MyImage.png, etc) but to no avail. The HTML page is located at /Users/John/bs/index.html. The program acting as a server is in the same directory.
If I open the page directly from the URL bar, file:///Users/John/bs/index.html it works fine, showing the image.
I don't know if this is a problem of relative path from the host root (which I ignore where it is), or some issue with the browser for accessing the page via the web server.
Here is a snippet of the Lisp code:

```
(defun serve (request-handler)
  (let ((socket (socket-server 8080)))
    (unwind-protect
       (loop (with-open-stream (stream (socket-accept socket))
                 (let* ((url    (parse-url (read-line stream)))
                        (path   (car url))
                        (header (get-header stream))
                        (params (append (cdr url) 
                                        (get-content-params stream header)))
                        (*standard-output* stream))
                   (funcall request-handler path header params))))
       (socket-server-close socket))))

(defun request-handler (path header params)
   (princ "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
   (terpri)
   (terpri)
   (with-open-file (in "bs/index.html")
      (copy-stream in *standard-output*)))

(serve #'request-handler)
```

Has anybody had the same issue? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Leo, please provide some of the code used on the Common-Lisp server application you wrote - it would help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Don't put it in a comment - edit your question...

Comment: Also, is your file name hard coded in your code? if so, your server won't serve any other file.

Comment: I'm not a Lisp programmer, but it seems to me that `name` refers to the `params` instead of the `path`, so that no matter what path your browser requests, `name` is always false unless something is requested in the query (after the path)... also, where does your code open any file that isn't `bs/index.html`? - **If your server doesn't serve it, your browser can't have it**.

Comment: I had to cut out a lot of lines to leave only the essential, but like I mentioned before, the page is served by the server, it's only the images that are not displayed.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly - **the server is also in charge of serving the images**... so, this is why observing the server's code in relation to the images is important.

Comment: Let's see if I understand it: the server serves the html page to the browser. The browser sees the reference to the image and requests this to the server. The server then serves the image. Is that right? How is this different from the case where I simply load the page by typing its URL in the URL bar? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Slightly different (might be a typo): the server serves the html page to the browser. The browser sees the **URL** for the image and requests this from the **server** ... when you use the browser to view a file from the disk, the browser translates the URL's to a relative or absolute path and asks the OS for a file answering that path. However, when the browser receives the page from a web-server, it sends a new HTTP request with the image's URI... In other words, when you use `file://` the OS acts as the server. When you use `http://`, your server should answer the call.

Comment: OK, but in that case why would it be different using file:// or http://? How come in the former case I get the image but not in the latter?

Comment: `file://` uses the Operating System as a server, so the browser requests the data from the OS. In contrast, the `http://` uses YOUR server, the browser requests the data from YOUR server. The OS knows the images and can provide the images to the browser. Does YOUR server know the images? can it provide the images to the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93425/discussion-between-leo-and-myst).

Comment: since the program does not serve the image, a browser will not be able to successfully request it. The program only responds with a single HTML response, which barely looks like it's doing HTTP.

Comment: A part of the code is from 'Land of Lisp': http://landoflisp.com/webserver.lisp

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately it does not cover how to serve binary files. I'm trying to patch it now.

Answer (score 1):

When your browser contacts your web server (the code you have written), any link that doesn't start with a "scheme" (usually "http://" or "https://") and a hostname will be taken as relative to the page fetched. This means that your browser will send a request to the same server for the resource "/Users/John/bs/images/MyImage.png" and unless your server can send the image back over the stream, it will show up as a broken image on the page.

The trivial fix (which will let it work on *your* computer) is to change the image URL to "file://localhost//Users/John/bs/images/MyImage.png", but that is the wrong fix. The correct fix is to dispatch on the requested path and serve the base HTML page when needed, or the image when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. The relative path should be relative to the file calling the image, so you wouldn't want to go all the way back to /Users/John.

```
<img src="images/MyImage.png"/>
```